# If it was to turn out that there are five different Higgs Fields how would each interact differently with other particles?

Tags: higgs

I have read before that there may be five different types of Higgs Fields.  If this was to turn out to be the case then which Higgs Fields would give which particles mass?

Comment: I suggest to cite a reference, ideally a link.